# Why am I getting "e.on is not a function" when uploading a file from React app to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, google-cloud-storage

I'm using a file input component from the React-Bootstrap library to select an image file from my machine. Then, I'm attempting to upload the image to a Google Cloud Storage bucket from memory. I'm getting a console error "TypeError: e.on is not a function" and the image is not uploaded to the bucket. I'm also using Next.js, in case that's a useful clue.

Here's the upload function:

```
  async function uploadImages() {
    // Create a client from a Google service account key
    const storage = new Storage({credentials: googleKeysJSON});
    console.log('storage: ', storage); //debug

    // Set the params for call to Google Cloud Storage
    const bucketName = 'my-bucket-name';
    const destination = imageInput.name;
    const content = imageInput.file;

    await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(destination).save(content);
  }
```

`imageInput` looks like this:

[image: screenshot of object]

If I change `content` to a string, the upload works and a new object appears in the bucket.

Here's the console error I'm getting:

```
client.js:1 TypeError: e.on is not a function
    at destroyer (index.js:1:40853)
    at eval (index.js:1:41568)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at pipeline (index.js:1:41512)
    at eval (file.js:2914:29)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at async_retry__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_18__.retries (file.js:2892:1)
    at RetryOperation.runAttempt [as _fn] (index.js:42:1)
    at RetryOperation.attempt (retry_operation.js:116:1)
    at run (index.js:55:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at retry (index.js:58:1)
    at File.save (file.js:2891:29)
    at eval (create-spot.tsx:167:56)
    at step (tslib.es6.mjs:147:1)
    at Object.eval [as next] (tslib.es6.mjs:128:44)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (_async_to_generator.js:3:1)
    at _next (_async_to_generator.js:20:1)
    at eval (_async_to_generator.js:27:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (_async_to_generator.js:16:1)
    at _uploadImages (create-spot.tsx:158:18)
    at uploadImages (create-spot.tsx:158:18)
    at handleImageButtonClick (create-spot.tsx:146:5)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js:9288:1)
    at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:26140:1)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3991:1)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:9287:1)
    at dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay (react-dom.development.js:6465:1)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6457:1)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:6430:1)
```

I tried reading code linked in the error trace, but it's all Greek to me.